# How would you divide a circumference into 12 equal segments in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui

I'm building an iOS app using SwiftUI and right now I'm trying to display a circumference divided into 12 equal segments, so it looks like that:

[image: 12 segments]

So far, I achieved it by using 12 circles, and trimming them to 1/12 of the circumference length (added 0.001 to have some space between these segments):

```
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:0.001, to: 1/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:1/12 + 0.001, to: 2/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:2/12 + 0.001, to: 3/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:3/12 + 0.001, to: 4/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:4/12 + 0.001, to: 5/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:5/12 + 0.001, to: 6/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
            }
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:6/12 + 0.001, to: 7/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:7/12 + 0.001, to: 8/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:8/12 + 0.001, to: 9/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:9/12 + 0.001, to: 10/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:10/12 + 0.001, to: 11/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from:11/12 + 0.001, to: 12/12 - 0.001)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
            }
        }
        .padding(30)
```

So the real question is: ***how would you implement such a division more elegantly?***

Comment: How are you measuring "elegance"?

Comment: @ScottHunter in this case, I'm talking about using a shorter, more effective solution

Comment: There are many tutorials about drawing a clock - maybe you can find inspiration there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code a bit more elegant is

```
ZStack {
    ForEach(0..<12, id: \.self) { index in
        Circle()
            .trim(from:Double(index) / 12 + 0.001, to: Double(index + 1) / 12 - 0.001)
            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 25)
    }
}
.padding(30)
```

but there are more elegant ways for example `Shape` and/or `Canvas` with some trigonometry.